# jQuery - if body has a class of X then change rotation speed of slider to X

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to write a function for featured slider.

Basically, on one page I want the rotate speed to be 10000 and on another page I want the speed to be 3000.

I have the two functions separately - which works - but i know there would be a cleaner/better way of doing it without repeating all the code...

Can anyone help?

```
$(function(){
  $("body.homePage #featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 10000, true);  
  $("body.homePage #featured").hover(  
    function() {  
      $("body.homePage #featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);
    },  
    function() {  
      $("body.homePage #featured").tabs("rotate",10000,true);  
    }
  );    
});

$(function(){
  $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 3000, true);  
  $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").hover(  
    function() {  
      $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);
    },  
    function() {  
      $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").tabs("rotate",3000,true);  
    }
  );    
});
```

Something like

```
if ($('body').hasClass('homePage')) {
  $("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 10000, true);  
  $("#featured").hover(  
    function() {  
      $("#featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);
    },  
    function() {  
      $("#featured").tabs("rotate",10000,true);  
    }
  );   
} else { 
  $("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 3000, true);  
  $("#featured").hover(  
    function() {  
      $("#featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);
    },  
    function() {  
      $("#featured").tabs("rotate",3000,true);  
    }
  );   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    // if body has class X speed will be 10000, else 3000
    var rotateSpeed = $("body").hasClass('X') ? 10000 : 3000;

    $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", rotateSpeed, true);  
    $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").hover(  
    function() {  
    $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);},  
    function() {  
    $("body.boatDetailsPage #featured").tabs("rotate",rotateSpeed,true);  
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of this solution is you can add any number of different `body` classes to check against and apply different animation durations to each

```
$(function(){
  var duration = 0;
  var $body = $('body');
  var $featured = $body.find('#featured');

  if($body.is('.homePage')) {
    duration = 10000;
  } else if($body.is('.boatDetailsPage')) {
    duration = 3000;
  } 

  if(duration > 0) {        
    $featured
      .tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}})
      .tabs("rotate", duration, true)
      .hover(  
        function() {  
          $featured.tabs("rotate",0,true);
        },  
        function() {  
          $featured.tabs("rotate",duration,true);  
        }
      );    
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used this answer because as you said, it can be added to should we decide to use the slider on another page. Thanks :)

Comment: @V Neal - glad I could help. Please mark this answer as the official answer as this is the answer you've used.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotateBehavior(selector, time){
    $(selector)
      .tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}) 
      .hover(  
          rotateMe(selector, 0),  
          rotateMe(selector, time)
      );

    rotateMe(selector, time);
}

function rotateMe(selector, time){
    $(selector).tabs("rotate", time,true);
}

$(function(){
    var time = $('body').hasClass('homePage') ? 10000 : 3000;
    var selector = '#featured';
    rotateBehavior(selector, time);
});
```